# Problem in java android emulator installation

Tags: android

06/11 14:04:49: Launching 'app' on Pixel_3a_API_30_x86.
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.

List of apks:

```
[0] 'C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\Android_Studio_Java_Programming\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'
Installation failed due to: ''cmd package install-create -r -t --user current --full --dont-kill --skip-verification -S 2761490' returns error 'Unknown failure: cmd: Can't find service: package''
Retry
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this.The easy way is to go to AVD manager and create a non Play Store Supported Virtual Device and run the app there.

The second option is this
[disable test only mode in gradle.properties](https://gist.github.com/xujiaao/5fd127a72979cdc3c70dcc1324786f87)